# How to use Semantic-ui multiple tabs with Python-Flask?

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2, semantic-ui

I want to use Jinjia render template.There are many Semantic-ui tabs on this page.
It's templates code.

```
{% extends "/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="ui centered cards">
{% for p in plan %}
<div class="ui card">
    <div class="ui segment" style="padding:0px;">
        <div class="ui top attached tabular menu" id="{{p,id}}">
            <a class="item active" data-tab="monthly">monthly</a>
            <a class="item" data-tab="quarterly">quarterly</a>
            <a class="item" data-tab="annualy">annualy</a>
            <a class="item" data-tab="yearly">yearly</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment active" data-tab="monthly">
          {{p.monthly}}{{p.currency}}
        </div>
        <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="quarterly">
          {{p.monthly}}{{p.currency}}
        </div>
        <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="annualy">
          {{p.monthly}}{{p.currency}}
        </div>
        <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="yearly">
          {{p.monthly}}{{p.currency}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{%endfor%}
</div>
</body>
<script>
$('.menu .item')
  .tab()
;
</script>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

PS:I have introduced semanticui in base.html

{% for p in plan %}:When there are multiple targets to traverse, the tabs of the rendered page cannot be switched individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the jquery and Semantiv-ui documents carefully.
Then I carefully experimented and found out how TAB works.
Then wrote the following javascript code. I successfully implemented a separate switch for TAB.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu .item").click(function(){
    var datatab = $(this).attr("data-tab");
    $(this).closest("div").children(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).closest("div").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest("div").siblings("[data-tab="+datatab+"]").addClass("active");
});
});
</script>
```